# PHP preg_replace v ltrim to remove leading white space

Tags: php, preg-replace

Are

```
preg_replace('/^\s+/', '', $str)
```

and

```
ltrim($str)
```

exactly the same?

According to http://www.php.net/trim, trim removes the following

- " " (ASCII 32 (0x20)), an ordinary space.
- "\t" (ASCII 9 (0x09)), a tab.
- "\n" (ASCII 10 (0x0A)), a new line (line feed).
- "\r" (ASCII 13 (0x0D)), a carriage return.
- "\0" (ASCII 0 (0x00)), the NUL-byte.
- "\x0B" (ASCII 11 (0x0B)), a vertical tab.

\s removes "white space" but I cannot find an exact definition of what that is.  I'd like to replace the former with ltrim, but it must have the exact same functionality.

Comment: `\s` will match for the first 4. It *won't* match vertical tab, but i'm not sure about NUL-byte. So unless you actually want to KEEP the  last and possibly 2nd to last, I'd say switch to `ltrim`

Comment: also `ltrim` is likely to be faster, however regex evaluation performance improved a lot in recent php versions

Comment: `\s` includes also form feed (ascii 12 `0x0C`)

Answer (score 0):

Use `trim` series of functions ( `ltrim()`, `rtrim()`, and `trim()` ) instead of using regex. Since php already have defined these, why not use them instead of using regex.